# Auto return line with a label in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I'm using Visual Studio to develop my application in C# and I have a little problem with one of my label like the below picture show :

[image]

My label go outside the window. I have no idea how I can make an auto line return on my label.

If someone have any idea ?

Thank you in advance !

*PS : For French peoples, I know I have a typo on "enregistré" instead of "enregistrer".*

Comment: is label's "AutoSize" property set to TRUE?

Comment: @imsome1 Yes it is !

Comment: try after switching off AutoSize property. Set this property as False.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your label's `AutoSize` property to false and expand your label manually. If neccessary, also apply `Anchor` properties to resize your label when your form gets resized.

Comment: It works ! Thank, I accept your answer in 9 minutes ;)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.